I have a 2013 Chevy Malibu ls put a new computer brain in it but the motor want turn over
I have a 2013 Chevy Malibu and I put a new computer brain in it I can get the motor to turn over

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the dashboard light up? Are there any indicators on the dash? Any codes? Might you see a flashing green light which looks like a key? IIRC, you have to program the ECU for the car, with the VIN of the car as well as other things. Are you sure you got the right ECU (ie: does the numbers on the new ECU match the old one?) What was car doing with the old ECU where you found you needed to change it out?
